# cuda binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (6.1) not found

Tags: rendering

I need help. I just bought an Alienware aurora r5 and it has a nvidia geforce gtx 1070 founders edition. I'm getting this error what do I do?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://developer.blender.org/T48544 or here: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?401097-GTX-1070-CUDA-binary-kernel-for-this-graphics-card-compute-capability-(6-1)-not-foun or here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCbdHwBA-q4

Comment: @Justin you could post Dingto's reply as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just quote  [Developer Thomas Dinges' (dingto) post](https://developer.blender.org/T48544)

> In order to support Pascal cards, we need to build kernels with the CUDA Toolkit 8. There is only a RC of the CUDA Toolkit 8 available yet, and so far only for registered developers. https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
>
> As soon as the final release is here we will build Blender with sm_61 kernels.