# Cuda "compute capability 6.1" error when installing new card

Tags: cycles-render-engine

i recently installed a new NVidia card also installed recent drivers when I try to render in cycles I get the message "cuda binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability 6.1 not found" not sure what this means.

Comment: possibly duplicate of  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61163/cuda-binary-kernel-for-this-graphics-card-compute-capability-6-1-not-found

Comment: it would be nice, if you look at this thread and post a final answer yourself when you get a solution (if there will be no better answers by that time).